# when iframe page refreshes it redirect to the main page not to the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My website uses the iframe to load content inside div element. 
My problem is when a page is refresh it redirect to the main page not to the current page.

Here is the part of the code.

```
     <a  href="promotion.jsp">Promotion</a>
```

And here is the javascript function I used.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var url;
        $('a').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            url = $(this).attr('href');
            if(undefined != url){
                window.frames["page-wrapper"].src = url;
                clickFront();
            }
        });

        $("button").click(function() {
            checkUrlandId(url,this.id);         
        });

    });
```

`clickFront()` is function that enable and disable some top menu bar button functionalities.

So when I click menu item(Approvals) page changed. After that page refreshes it redirect to the main page not to the current page.

Here are two screenshots. First one is before clicking the menu item and second one is after clicking the menu item.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

After clicking the menu item url is not changing.

I read that we can use cookies or javascript localstorage to save the url to do this? Can someone help me... I'm a newbie to the js.

Comment: clicking on an anchor tag will load a new page, unless you **prevent** this **Default** behaviour

Comment: I don't want to load a new page. The side menu is static but the right side of the page is dynamic

Comment: You need to use a cookie or the hash to allow the refresh

Comment: I'm a newbie to js. So can someone help me to use cookies to page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect  `window.frames["page-wrapper"].src = url;` to be
`window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;`

Anyway. If you need the iFrame change to survive a refresh and a bookmark, you need to use the hash in the page:

```
$(function(){
    var url = location.hash?decodeURIComponent(hash.substring(1)):"";
    if (url) window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(undefined != url){
            location.hash=encodeURIComponent(url);
            window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;
            clickFront();
        }
    });

});
```

If URLs are external, you really need target.

Localstorage

```
$(function(){
    var url = localStorage.getItem("url");
    if (url) window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(undefined != url){
            window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;
            localStorage.setItem("url",url);
            clickFront();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Using above method my side menu is disappear. I'm using iframe here for a reason. That is my side menu remain same and other parts are changed.

Comment: this is not working. According to thiis URL is changing but the page is not loading...

Comment: I would need to see it in action and check the console

Comment: I read that js localstorge can save the url and when page refreshes it can use saved url or we can use cookies. I'm a newbie to js. so can u help me...

Comment: see update.....

Comment: Now I can't  go to the main page. When I click the home button to go to the main page it's remain in the current page. And also if I closed the tab and run the project again it redirects to the last visited page not to the main page...

Comment: I have no way of knowing why. Perhaps I have a typo, perhaps you pasted it wrong. I cannot test this code for you because you have other code at your site

Comment: Here is the line for redirect to the main page. but this button is not working. It refreshes page...                                                                                                 <button id="home" class="btn" style="float: left" onclick=document.location.href='../GUI/home.jsp';>
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></button>

Comment: Why is that not type=button ?

Comment: So I used this. But still not working.                          <button type="button">

Comment: `type="button" onclick="location.href='../GUI/home.jsp';"`  will load the homepage. If not, look in the console for errors

Comment: I did this and it works perfectly now.                  <button id="home" class="btn" style="float: left" onclick="home()">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></button> . Then I wrote a js function to load the home page. Before load it I clear the localstorage.                                  function home (){    
         
            localStorage.clear();
            document.location.href='home.jsp';
       }

Comment: Thanks for your help...

Comment: And I change your function a bit. I put window.frames["page-wrapper"].src = url;    instead of window.frames["page-wrapper"].location = url;

Comment: I am surprised. I would expect location since it is a window object when you get it by name and an iframe object when you get it by getElementById or ByName[0]

Answer (score 1):

Look at sample below, everything works as expected

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function(a) {
  a.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.frames.frame1.src = a.getAttribute('href');
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow main page</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2308005/medet-tleukabiluly?tab=profile">My profile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629581/node-js-obtain-access-token">Question: Node.js obtain access token</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<iframe id="frame1" width="500" height="200" src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629578/when-iframe-page-refreshes-it-redirect-to-the-same-page-not-to-the-main-page"></iframe>
```

Comment: i need load external html files inside #page-wrapper frame