# Node.js obtain access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, httprequest

I have been given the following documentation (https://autovit.zendesk.com/hc/ro/articles/214077685-Obtinere-token-acces) and I want to call this api to get the access token for subsequent requests.

I do not understand how you can multiple parameters

```
-u 79: 70f8c636a503d50ac6c411597b4cc402
```

The post request I have been given is:
How can we help? dealers partners API Autovit

```
POST https://ssl.autovit.ro/api/open/oauth/token/
-X POST
-H "Accept: application / json"
-u 79: 70f8c636a503d50ac6c411597b4cc402 [client_id and client_secret]
-d "username = test24 @ test. pl "  [username dealer Autovit]
-d" password = 123456789 " [Autovit user password]
-d" grant_type = password "
```

*The code in [ ] are comments by the provider*

I will use the request npm module and know that I have to do the following code, **but I am not sure how to pass the client_id (in this case 79) and the client_secret**, any help would be much appreciated.

```
request({
  url: 'https://ssl.autovit.ro/api/open/oauth/token/',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: {
    user: 'test24 @ test. pl',
    pass: '123456789'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'password'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
  console.log("Access Token:", json.access_token);
});
```

Following documentation [link](https://www.autovit.ro/api/doc/#api-Oauth2-PostToken) I can see that the client id and secret are parameters. So maybe I could use the as the json field1 parameters as below??? :

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');

//Lets configure and request
request({
    url: 'https://modulus.io/contact/demo', //URL to hit
    qs: {from: 'blog example', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
    method: 'POST',
    //Lets post the following key/values as form
    json: {
        field1: 'data',
        field2: 'data'
    }
}, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusCode, body);
}
});
```

Comment: that looks like curl command line options, so that `-u` should be `-u 79:70f...etc` ... not there's **no space** after the `:` ... this sets the "user:password" for the request ... as for your `request` code, you've assumed to use auth: parameter for the `username` and `password` **data** in the curl example (-d sets data) ... and I don't even know why you assumed to use `form:` parameter for the `grant_type` data - it's like you picked random things to put in random parameters! Read curl manual to understand what that command line example is doing https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html ...

Answer (score 1):

The -u option is for Basic authentication. You can include it in the URL or in the Authorization header as "Basic {auth_hash}".

This article shows each in an example - https://www.haykranen.nl/2011/06/21/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js-using-the-request-module/

Comment: Hi, thank you,  i understand how to apply the user name and password but how do I pass the client id and password?

Comment: You need to set all -d values as key/value pairs on the request body. Your client id and secret should be used for Basic authentication. If you can't get it I'll post the code when I get to a computer.